# Enrich mediator Issue with Json in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Below is the sample service I have created to Highlight the issue I am facing in my project(where the request and response are very big and this issue is repeating at many places).

Request :
{
        "id" : "3",
        "parts" : ["Screen"]
}

Actual Response :
{
    "id": "3",
    "parts": "Screen",
    "make": "Tamsung"
}

Desired Response  :

{
    "id": "3",
    "parts": ["Screen"],
    "make": "Tamsung"
}

---

Issues :

1. "parts": "Screen",

   should have been like below

   "parts": ["Screen"],

   i.e. it does not remain array anymore. I understand the array consist only one element. But the third party system to which the output of this service is sent as input(request) expects the element as array. So I need it to be as array.

---

arrayTest.xml :

```
        <enrich>
            <source clone="true" type="inline">
                <make xmlns="">Tamsung</make>
            </source>
            <target action="child" xpath="//jsonObject"/>
        </enrich>
        <enrich>
            <source clone="true" xpath="//jsonObject"/>
            <target type="body"/>
        </enrich>

        <respond/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
</resource>
```

I think , I cannot recreate the message using payloadFactory  because,
   " the message(payload) I am modifying with enrich mediator is a "huge and dynamic response from Third party service". This response I need to modify/enrich at many places in my service and send it to another third party service as input.

With "Dynamic" I mean, some things in the message are different(change) everytime service receives the request, depending on some factors in the request received by the third party service which provides message as input to this service.

so I think I cannot recreate message using payloadFactory like this

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
         <format>{"id" : $1, "parts" : $2, "make" : "Tamsung"}</format>
          <args>
                     <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.id"></arg>
                     <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.parts"></arg>
          </args>
    </payloadFactory>
```

as it will be dynamic response from a third party service. So we cannot recreate the message in payloadFactory it being not static.

Answer (score 0):

Use below parameter to preserve single element arrays in JSON payloads when the transformation happens.

```
synapse.json.to.xml.processing.instruction.enabled=true
```

The parameter needs to be added in /conf/synapse.properties, to achieve this functionality. Finally, restart the server and you will be able to resolve the above-mentioned issue.